# GridView - set selected index by searching through data keys

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a GridView which has DataKey[0] as productId.
If i have for instance productId = 54, is there any way to search through all
GridView item and set as selected the one who has DataKEy[0] = 54?

For a drop down list i have :

```
ddlProducts.Items.FindByValue(lblProduct.Text.ToString())).Selected = true
```

Is anything similar for GridView?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matt was very close. He forgot the "Value" property:

```
foreach(GridViewRow myRow in GridView1.Rows)
{
    if(GridView1.DataKeys[myRow.RowIndex].Value.Equals("keyValue"))
    {
        GridView1.SelectedIndex = myRow.RowIndex;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will probably need to do this in a foreach loop:

```
foreach(GridViewRow myRow in GridView1.Rows)
{
    if(GridView1.DataKeys[myRow.RowIndex].Equals("keyValue"))
    {
         GridView1.SelectedIndex = myRow.RowIndex;
         break;
    }
}
```

You won't get very good performance from this if you have a lot of rows, though.

Comment: One question please: "in GridView1.Rows" will only take my first 10 records (pageSize beeing 10 in my case). Is there a way to iterate thru ALL the records from the GridView? Because the product can be on page 4 for instance....thanks.